# tf.nn.embedding_lookup - row or column?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

This is a very simple question. I'm learning tensorflow and converting my numpy-written code using Tensorflow.

I have word embedding matrix defined  `U = [embedding_size, vocab_size]` therefore each column is the embedding vector of each word.

I converted `U` into TF like below:

```
U = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([embedding_size, vocab_size], -0.1, 0.1))
```

So far, so good.

Now I need to look up each word's embedding for training. I assume it would be

```
tf.nn.embedding_lookup(U, word_index)
```

My question is because my embedding is a column vector, I need to look up like this `U[:,x[t]]` in numpy.

How does TF figure out it needs to return the row OR column by word_index?

What's the default? Row or column? 
If it's a row vector, then do I need to transpose my embedding matrix?

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup
doesn't mention this. If anyone could point me to right resource, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `params` is a single tensor, the [`tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params, ids)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup) operation treats `ids` as the indices of **rows** in `params`.  If `params` is a list of tensors or a partitioned variable, then `ids` still correspond to rows in those tensors, but the `partition_strategy` (either `"div"` or `"mod"`) determines how the `ids` map to a particular row.

As [Aaron suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46436638/3574081), it will probably be easiest to define your embedding `U` as having shape `[vocab_size, embedding_size]`, so that you can use `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()` and [related functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup_sparse).

Alternatively, you can use the `axis` argument to [`tf.gather()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) to select columns from `U`:

```
embedding = tf.gather(U, word_index, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

U should be vocab_size x embedding_size, the transpose of what you have now.